# Linear Temporal Logic (LTL) questions

Tags: logic, verification, proof, temporal, model-checking

[] = always

O = next

! = negation

<> = eventually

---

Wondering is it []<> is that equivalent to just []?

---

Also having a hard time understanding how to distribute temporal logic.

1. [][] (a OR !b)
2. !<>(!a AND b)
3. []([] a ==> <> b)

Answer (score 2):

I'll use the following notations:

> F = eventually
> G = always
> X = next
> U = until

In my model-checking course, we defined LTL the following way:

> LTL: p | φ ∩ ψ | ¬φ | Xφ | φ U ψ

With F being a syntactic sugar for :

> F (future)
> Fφ = True U φ

and G:

> G (global)
> Gφ = ¬F¬φ

With that, your question is :

> Is it true that : Gφ ?= GFφ
>
> GFφ <=> G (True U φ)

Knowing that :

> P ⊧ φ U ψ <=> exists i >= 0: P_(>= i) ⊧ ψ AND forall 0 <= j < i : P_(<= j) ⊧ φ

From that, we can clearly see that GFφ indicates that it must always be true that φ will be always be verified after some time i, and before that (j before i) True must be verified (trivial).
But Gφ indicates that φ must always be true, "from now to forever" and not "from i to forever".

Answer (score 0):

**G** *p* indicates that at all times *p* holds. **GF** *p* indidcates that at all times, eventually *p* will hold. So while the infinite trace *pppppp*... satisfies both of the specifications, an infinite trace of the form *p(!p)(!p!)p(!p)p*... satisfies only **GF** *p* but not **G** *p*.

To be clear, both these example traces need to contain infinitely many locations, where *p* holds. But in the case of **GF** *p*, and only in this case, it is acceptable that there be locations in between, where *p* does not hold.

So the short answer to the above question by counterexample is: no, those two specifications aren't the same.